# How to convert a TensorFlow JSON graph model to .tflite?

Tags: android, json, tensorflow, model, tensorflow-lite

I am porting [this TensorFlow JS tutorial](https://medium.com/tensorflow/real-time-human-pose-estimation-in-the-browser-with-tensorflow-js-7dd0bc881cd5) to Android. I must convert [this JSON graph TensorFlow model](https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/savedmodel/posenet/resnet50/float/model-stride32.json) to .tflite so I can use it there.

I googled about TensorFlow model conversion tools but couldn't find anything. I also looked at whether the Android TensorFlow-lite library has a way to import these graph models, but I didn't find anything either.

I tried converting it with the following Python script I found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api#exporting_a_savedmodel_), but it expects a .pb file:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()
open("converted_model.tflite", "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

Comment: It's 2021 - still no way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

TFLite converter currently doesn't support loading tf-js models. However, you could try using tflite's own posenet model (https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/models/pose_estimation/overview)

Hope this could make things easier.